# Is there a way using to check if the element I clicked on redirects me to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to see if there's a way to see if the DOM element I clicked on redirects me to another page or refreshes the page ? I'm building a chrome extension and I'm trying to handle any page refresh or some kind of submit that'd redirects me to another page so I can dispatch an Event when the page refreshs.
EDIT :
This is the code I want to run on page change

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('GET_TAB_ACTIVITIES', { detail: Activities }));
```

Activities is an Array that I want to send to my react app.

Comment: To know when the page is about to be redirected use the `window.beforeunload` event, however the code you can run under that event is limited as the page is in the process of being unloaded, so depending on your goal it may not be possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The thing is that I want to send the collected data from that page to my react app through the dispatchEvent, I'll update my question and add what I want to run when the page is changing.